# Hazelcast Best Practices for high volume

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am pretty new to Hazelcast and seeking some advice.

I have a service listening to various types of objects that I have to ultimately store in Hazelcast cache. Assuming there may be 1-5 million (or more) records for each type, I am wondering would it be better to have separate caches for each type, or a single cache for all the records irrespective of the type. The cache(s) need to be frequently updated.

What may be the pros and cons of both of these approaches?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a design decision, which would basically depend on how your application wants to use the data. For example, if your data was scattered across multiple caches then you would have to have multiple lookups but on the other hand, each cache would have specific type of data.

For Hazelcast, it does not really matter whether you store in one cache or multiple caches.